# How to solve the recursive algorithm stack overflow in a maze program?

Tags: c, stack-overflow

I have a simple program to solve the maze. But an error is reported: stack overflow. How can I solve the stack overflow?

In my code, `1` represents the wall, `0` represents the path that can be taken, and `$` represents the end. (1,2) is the starting point.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

void ShowMaze(char szMaze[][24],int nCount)
{
    
    for(int i=0;i<nCount;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\r\n",szMaze[i]);
    }
}

void Maze(char szMaze[][24],int x,int y)
{
    if(szMaze[x][y]=='$')
    {
        printf("Congratulations!\r\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (szMaze[x+1][y]=='$'||szMaze[x+1][y]=='0')
    {
        Maze(szMaze,x+1,y);
    }
    if (szMaze[x][y+1]=='$'||szMaze[x][y+1]=='0')
    {
        Maze(szMaze,x,y+1);
    }
    if (szMaze[x-1][y]=='$'||szMaze[x-1][y]=='0')
    {
        Maze(szMaze,x-1,y);
    }
    if (szMaze[x][y-1]=='$'||szMaze[x][y-1]=='0')
    {
        Maze(szMaze,x,y-1);
    }
    
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char szMaze[][24]={
    "11111111111111111111111",
    "10111111111111111111111",
    "10000000001111111111011",
    "11111111011111100001011",
    "11111111011111101111011",
    "11111111000000000001$11",
    "11111111011111101111011",
    "11111111011111100000001",
    "11111111111111111111111"
    };
    int nRow=sizeof(szMaze)/sizeof(szMaze[0]);
    ShowMaze(szMaze,nRow);

    Maze(szMaze,1,2);
    
    system("pause");
    return 0
```

Comment: You never check for boundaries of your array. Your code will happily run hundreds of squares in each direction. That will ultimately deplete any stack no matter how large it is

Comment: You need to keep track on positions that you have already visited. If you don't, you end up with an endless loop which leads to SO

Comment: And it seems you are missing walls at position (0,0) (1,0) and (2,0)

Comment: OT: "(1,2) is the starting point" It's not really a problem but it's a bit funny that you start in the wall.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but `szMaze[x][y]` should better be `szMaze[y][x]` as you have rows in first index, columns in second

Comment: You call `Maze(szMaze,x,y-1);` in 2 cases. Should be `Maze(szMaze,x-1,y);` in one of them.

Comment: Take a very close look at this code: `if (szMaze[x-1][y]=='$'||szMaze[x-1][y]=='0')
    {
        Maze(szMaze,x,y-1);
    }` Do you see the bug?

Comment: @Gerhardh How can I modify my program? I don't think I need to do boundary checking. When my program returns to the upper level after four ifs, there is no problem, right?

Comment: @4386427 I find it and fixed it，but found the bug and fixed it, but it still reports an error

Comment: @CHAOSYD yes... see my first comment

Comment: If your maze is closed with `'1'` on all borders, you don't need boundary check. But until you changed your code and invalidated all comments, that was not the case. Modifying the question after comments were given should be avoided as some comments now don't make any sense any more.

Comment: @Gerhardh Invalidating comments is fine. Only changing questions so that answers do not make sense anymore is frowned upon. While there are no answers, this is not a problem. If the changes help to focus the question on the actual problem OP is asking about (or means to ask about) I actually appreciate this kind of editing.

Comment: @4386427 this is the crux of the problem.You are really steady and powerful.

Comment: Please fix your [mre]. At least soem `;}` is missing at the end. You could, in my opinion, make a better MRE if you avoid using windows.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid endless loops you need to mark positions that have already been visited.

Something like:

```
szMaze[x][y]='2'; // mark position as visited
if (szMaze[x+1][y]=='$'||szMaze[x+1][y]=='0')
{
    Maze(szMaze,x+1,y);
}
if (szMaze[x][y+1]=='$'||szMaze[x][y+1]=='0')
{
    Maze(szMaze,x,y+1);
}
if (szMaze[x-1][y]=='$'||szMaze[x-1][y]=='0')
{
    Maze(szMaze,x-1,y);
}
if (szMaze[x][y-1]=='$'||szMaze[x][y-1]=='0')
{
    Maze(szMaze,x,y-1);
}
szMaze[x][y]='0'; // release position
```

and don't start in the wall! Start like:

```
Maze(szMaze,1,2); ---->   Maze(szMaze,1,1);
```

**Note**

Your code don't do any boundary checking. Therefore it will only work when the maze has walls at all boundaries. Having such a requirement is kind of "okay" but I would prefer boundary checking instead.